# Foreign Key constraint error when performing fresh install of Piranha CMS

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, piranha-cms

Piranha CMS is a programmer oriented CMS (I prefer to write it since I've been downvoted last time!). I've spent all the afternoon trying to fix this problem : Whether I try to migrate from a Sql Compact Server Database to a SQL Server Database, or to start everything from scratch with an empty SQL Server Database, I get the following error :

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.category_dbo.sysuser_category_updated_by' on table 'category' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I am able to pass the first step (admin account and password creation), but this exception is thrown whenever I try to log in.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help !

**UPDATE**

The stack indicates where the error is coming from :

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method 
Start on type Piranha.Web.ApplicationModule threw an exception with the following
error message: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
 'FK_dbo.category_dbo.sysuser_category_updated_by' on table 'category' 
may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON 
DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors..]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9915300
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, 
HttpContext context) +254
```

There seem to be a problem with the Method Start of Piranha.Web.ApplicationModule.

Also I have noticed the configuration of Entity Framework is :

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

I wonder about the :

```
invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient
```

Since System.Data.SqlClient is the Provider mentionned in my connection string. But I don't know if it's relevant since it may just mean that EF is used to retrieve the data. But I wonder if there might not be a conflict since both your internal scripts and EF use this connection string with this provider that is mentionned. Also, I'm not sure, but I know that with code-first EF also creates meta-data when it creates a database. Perhaps since your internal scripts doesn't create them, EF considers that the DB doesn't exist ?

**Update 2**

I have some news, I have added

```
Database.SetInitializer<Piranha.DataContext>(null);
```

In Application_Start to avoid Database recreation. It seems to have solved the database re-creation problem. I no longer see the exception concerning the constraint. However now the PageController throws a null reference exception after trying to log in, and I still can't see anypage of the public website (The publc site throws an internal server error). My guess is that when I set the Initializer to null, it also prevents EF from populating the DB with the basic data of the Framework. That's a good step further, so it seems that the problem comes from the Piranha DataContext Configuration.

**Update 3**

Just to give more details :

When trying to log in, I'm redirected to manager/page which throws a null reference exception as I said before. This exception is thrown when I try to access most of the pages of the manager (I have tried template/pagelist, setting/userlist) however, when I try "manager/post" I get the following error :

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.post'.  
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.post'.
```

But the 'post' Table do exist in the Database... It's a fresh install, I only changed two things : the connection string, and the Database Initializer code I added in Global Asax.

Comment: As I mentioned before, Entity Framework should not create the tables in the database. Also there's no problem in using EF to map an existing database (like used in Piranha CMS) without the __MigrationHistory table present in the database. Entity framework doesn't Seed the database with default data either, this is also done with SqlScripts. In fact EF isn't used for anything else than a LINQ-query interface for the end-application.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the explanation ! I'll try what you suggest in your update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for error is Schema name in my case.

**Solution:**
You require to have database objects belonging to dbo schema, if you've installed on fresh database with different schema name, it will throw this error. To fix it, change schema name of those tables to dbo and it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see, in version 2.2.0 there is not a constraint for table "category" with the name "FK_dbo.category_dbo.sysuser_category_updated_by". I guess something went wrong installing a fresh version.

If you have access to SQL server with a management tool (like 'SQLServer Management Studio'), try to run to following query against your Piranha-database:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='category' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY'
```

You should see three constraints, none of them with the word 'sysuser' in its name.

You might want to try a fresh install again, following the instructions here:
http://piranhacms.org/docs/introduction/getting-started

Before you proceed with the web installer, you should create a clean empty database using SQL Server Management Studio. You can run these SQL-commands in the Management Studio:

```
-- create new user
CREATE LOGIN piranha2 WITH PASSWORD = 'piranha2' 
GO
-- create new empty database
CREATE DATABASE piranha2 
GO
-- select new database
USE piranha2
GO
-- assign user to database
CREATE USER piranha2 FOR LOGIN piranha2
GO
-- add role to user
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'piranha2'
GO
```

After that, open Web.config, look for section "connectionStrings". You should see a couple of lines. Add a new line in this section with this content (don't forget to use your own servername or ip-address after "server="):

```
<add name="piranha" connectionString="server=192.168.1.1;database=piranha2;user id=piranha2;password=piranha2;multipleactiveresultsets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Start the installer. It should find your database and create tables and constraints.
Hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks for four message Gerard! I've checked the constraints with Management Studio and I have found 3 constraints as you said : 'fk_category_created_by', 'fk_category_permalink_id', 'fk_category_updated_by'. Actually I have already read the link that you've sent me, I've even browsed Github, and your blog's comments, SO, the web... to try to get all the related information that was available.

I created at least three different empty databases, I even uninstalled and reinstalled Pirhana. What happens is that the tables are created, but I run into this error whenever I try to login.

Comment: One thing that I haven't try though is to create a new MVC project to check if it solves the problem. I'll keep you informed

Comment: I've just tried with every fresh : Fresh Project + Fresh Database but i'm still getting exactly the same exception. My production server is running SQLServer 2012

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're providing is a typical Entity Framework error when trying to create a DbContext in the database. The only problem is that Entity Framework is not responsible for creating the tables in Piranha CMS, this is done by internal SqlScripts embedded in the framework dll.

If the tables are created successfully in the database and you still get this error when trying to log in, my only guess is that Entity Framework is for some reason using an incorrect Connection String trying to create the database somewhere else. Although I'm puzzled how this could happen through misconfiguration.

Can you access the public site after install?

**UPDATE**

I've created a new Blank MVC Application, installed PiranhaCMSMvc into it, installed the database and logged into the manager without problems. I've pushed the blank project to this repo:

https://github.com/tidyui/Blank

Download this source code and see if it works for you **after** you've modified the connection string. If it works, try to compare the projects to see what is causing your error. If it doesn't work then there's something else wrong with your setup that is conflicting somehow. Keep me updated!

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your help Hakan. I'm puzzled too, unfortunately I can't reach any page of the website after install. It throws me the same exception concerning the constraint error. The only solution is to start everything from scratch and run into the same problem again.

Comment: After Gerard's post, I have created a Fresh project with everything fresh (Database, etc...), the only thing I changed is the connection string. I know that the connection string is okay because I can browse the Databse in the Server Explorer. Moreover, I can see the Tables that have been created after the first step of the install. I really have no idea about what's going on, what a unexpected situation.

Comment: I have updated my post, the problem seems to come from the Method Start of Piranha.Web.ApplicationModule.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check above!

Comment: I've done it and unfortunately I get the exception error concerning the Constraint on the category Table. I've done it using an empty Database on my production server. However once again I can see that the Tables have been created. It's very frustating, are you testing it on MSServer 2012 Hakan ?

Comment: I'm running out of ideas... I'll try to download the source code of the CMS to debug. I hope that I will be able to manage. Where can I find the 2.2.0 sources on Github ?

Comment: Hi Håkan, I have the exact same issue at the moment with a fresh install. Do you still have that blank project? The link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, I spent 2 days on it so I had no choice but to change CMS. I'm running late because of this problem. Fortunately I only had created a couple of pages. I'm currently moving to Umbraco. I've played with it this afternoon and it's actually less complicated than what I heard so it should do the trick. It's also perfectly working on my production server.

However, I still have an other project that I would like to keep on Piranha CMS. Since I've planned to move it from Compact SQL to SQL Server too, I'm really concerned with this issue.

Comment: Out of curiousity, did your installation work with SqlCompact but not with SqlServer? In that case it's even more strange, I have deployed Piranha CMS on SqlServer 2003 up to the latest version and Azure.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't reply because I was in a rush and I was unable to set up a VM at that time. Now I have much more time. Yes I agree, it seems that the problem comes from the environment but I really don't see what I need to change. It's running under SQL Server 2012. I've got the exact same issue with my other project, that's strange. If you have ideas I would be happy to try them !

Comment: Yes that is the case ! It works perfectly with SqlCompact but I get this error with SqlServer. Actually I switch back and forth from SqlServer to SqlCompact to try debug this issue

Comment: Have you been able to test it on SQL Server 2012 Hakan ? I've been able to avoid a big issue with the customer by moving to Umbraco but clearly, I regret Pirhana. Umbraco is so like Joomla... I'm no longer doing real ASP.NET, I have to code everything in my browser... It's wasting the power and flexibility of ASP.NET MVC. I really look forward to solve this issue, Pirhana is indeed the best CMS.

Comment: I'm running several production sites with SQL Server 2012 so that's no problem. I'm still a bit puzzled by you error since I can't reproduce it and no one else has reported it. A work around could always be to create the database with SqlCompact. Then you can script the entire database and create the schema + data in an SQL Server database. Then just change the connection string to point at SQL Server.

Comment: unfortunately it is exactly what I've tried to do yesterday. But no way, I'm still getting the exact same error. The incredible thing is that I'm getting this error on every project, whether it's an existing project or a blank project. When I created the blank project, I just changed the connection string to poing to a blank database on my production server. My last chance is that I'm currently using MVC4, I'll try with MVC5 to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment yet, so have to give a second answer:
My previous answer didn't make sense so i have to make something up with you.
If you still want to investigate some time:
to re-produce your problem i've created a VHD with Windows 7 Pro-N (un-activated), MS SQL 2012 Express and VS 2013 Express Web. You can run this as virtual machine either under Windows 7 Virtual PC or Windows 8 Hyper-V. With the Blank project of Hakan I was not able to reproduce your problem. However, if you manage to re-produce your problem in this virtual machine, you can share the VHD with Hakan so he can take a look what is happening (of course if he's willing to do so).
Also, what i'm wondering: if you rename the affected table or drop it, is the error-message moving to another table and/or constraint? Of course it is not a solution to drop the table, but it might tell more about what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Gerard! I haven't been able to reproduce the errors, and since it most likely has to do with the environment I highly doubt they will occur in your image. If they do I'll be more than happy to assist! Regards